# How to check the type of value stored in redis

Tags: redis

Is there a way, in Redis, to know, the type of value a key has stored? Where it's a hash, list, set?

I am sure, this will come handy, if you didn't design the code and trying to debug any issue and what commands such as HGET, HGETALL...LRANGE...to use?

Any comments/opinion would be helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know the data type of the value of a given key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077591/how-do-i-know-the-data-type-of-the-value-of-a-given-key)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `TYPE` command is useful: http://redis.io/commands/type
the `OBJECT` command might help too: http://redis.io/commands/object