# How do I know the data type of the value of a given key?

Tags: redis, command-line-interface

I can't seem to find useful information about Redis commands. I want to know the data type of the value of a given key. For instance to list all the keys of my database I run the following command:

```
 keys *
```

In my setup, I get the following result:

```
 1) "username:testuser:uid"
 2) "uid:1:first"
 3) "uid:1:email"
 4) "uid:1:hash"
 5) "global:next_uid"
 6) "members:email"
 7) "uid:1:username"
 8) "uid:1:last"
 9) "uid:1:salt"
 10) "uid:1:access"
 11) "uid:1:company"
 12) "email:testuser@gmail.com:uid"
 13) "uid:1:phone_number"
```

How do I know what data type the key `members:email` contains? I tried to run `get members:email` but and I get the error `(error) ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you try and `GET aList` it will give you that error. Same with hashes. Lists and hashes have their own GET-like commands, namely: HGET, LRANGE and others. In that sense, it's not strictly a key value store, but has data structures that are treated slightly differently.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use the type command:
http://redis.io/commands/type

Comment: The `OBJECT` command might help too: https://redis.io/commands/object

Answer (score 7):

See below from docs:

```
redis> SET key1 "value"
    "OK"
    redis> LPUSH key2 "value"
    (integer) 1
    redis> SADD key3 "value"
    (integer) 1
    redis> TYPE key1
    "string"
    redis> TYPE key2
    "list"
    redis> TYPE key3
    "set"
    redis>
```